# Setting a timeout on my swing application

Tags: java, swing, listener

I have a Java swing application with several panel and transitions between them (button, inputs ...).
What I want now is to set a timeout for my whole application (that will logout the user on my software), and bring back the user to another JPanel (I don't need help for that part).

After some research I have found something that seems to work (not fully implemented atm), I'm adding Key, MouseMotion and MouseWheel listener to ALL my swing elements and reloading my timer for any user action.

I wanted to know if there is any built-in function that can handle such a situation or a nicer way to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm adding Key, MouseMotion and MouseWheel listener to ALL my swing elements

You can check out [Application Inactivity](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/application-inactivity/) which does this using an `AWTEventListener` so you don't need to do it for all your components.

You provide the listener with an `Action` to invoke after your period of inactivity.