# Monitor interaction with child components of a top-level container

Tags: java, swing

In a Swing application, I want to monitor if any interaction with child components of a top-level container happened. Is there any built-in mechanism of Swing that would help me with this task?

My problem is that I want to close the container if the user has not interacted with it for some time. However, I would like to avoid adding instrumentation to all components (like specific listeners). Is that possible?

```
public static void addInactivityTimeout(final Container c, final long timeout) {
    final Timer t = new Timer(c.getName() + INACTIVITY_SUFFIX);
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        private long inactivityTime = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!hadInteraction(c)) {
                inactivityTime += INACTIVITY_POLLING_PERIOD;
                if (inactivityTime > timeout) {
                    c.setVisible(false);
                }
            } else {
                inactivityTime = 0;
            }
            t.cancel();
        }
    }, INACTIVITY_POLLING_PERIOD, 
    INACTIVITY_POLLING_PERIOD);
}

public static boolean hadInteraction(Container c) {
    /**
     * Is there any method in Swing to help writing this 
     * function without adding extras instrumentation 
     * throughout the code ?
     */
}
```

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'built-in'. There are a bunch of different listeners available as appropriate to each component, listeners for action, document, changes, mouse.. If you mean 'one single listener for all' then no. See also [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: @AndrewThompson, thank you for the reference for the [link text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I'll try to include more information.

Comment: You can use an `AWTEventListner` to listen for events on all components. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260317/setting-a-timeout-on-my-swing-application/29260452#29260452.

Comment: @camickr Thank you for the help! Should I close my question because it is already answered?

Comment: @Eduardo, if you think it answers the question I will close it for you as a duplicate.