# Restart timer if mouse is moving

Tags: java, swing, timer, restart

I want to restart my program, if the mouse is not moving for 2 minutes. 
I tried to set a timer and restart it everytime the mouse moves, but nothing worked so far.
Is there someone who can help me with this problem?

```
frame.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer.purge();
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    frame.dispose();
                    try {
                        MyWeb neu = new MyWeb();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you share what you have done so far?

Comment: Sry, I have added my code. I used 5000ms for testing

Comment: Swing is not thread safe and you should not be using `java.util.Timer` for this task, instead, use a Swing `Timer`

Comment: thanks for you answer. Can I keep the mouseMotionListener and just use a Swing timer?

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260317/setting-a-timeout-on-my-swing-application/29260452#29260452

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Swing Timer

You want to use a Swing Timer ([`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html)) rather than a common Timer ([`java.util.Timer`](http://%60javax.swing.Timer%60)). See the [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

### Automatic threading

The Swing Timer is special in that it automatically handles the timer ticking on a background, and when eventually fired, the timer automatically handles running your task on the main GUI thread of Swing. So you need not concern yourself with the details of threading.

It is *very very very* important to never access your GUI widgets on a background thread. You *may* get away with it, or you may drastically disrupt your app. The Swing Timer was invented to handle the chore of counting down on a background thread yet switching back to the GUI thread to run the task’s code.

### `TimerTask` to shutdown your app

Write your work to be done on firing of the timer as a [`java.util.TimerTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimerTask.html).

### Algorithm

A Swing Timer can fire once or repeatedly. You want to fire once. Upon firing, shutdown your app.

Set up the timer when your app launches. Store a reference to that timer on your app. Configure the timer for your desired 2 minute countdown. Every time the mouse moves, call [`restart`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html#restart()) on the Swing Timer. So the 2 minute countdown keeps getting set back to 2 minutes. Your app may run for hours, with the 2 minute timer getting reset over and over and over again.

```
launch timer (2 mins) →  on mouse move  ↓ → timer fires → shutdown app
                      ↑ ← restart timer ←
```

### Shutdown versus restart

When the countdown expires, I am not sure if you meant to shutdown, relaunch, or merely re-initialize some state within your app. If the last one (re-init state), set your timer to fire repeatedly rather than once. The rest of the approach remains the same.

### Possible optimization

I do not know for certain, but I suspect resetting the timer on *every* mouse movement might be overkill, and might cost a bit of performance. Profile to see for yourself. If there does seem to be significant cost, just track the last time you reset the timer. To track that moment, use an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) object. Call [`Instant.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#now()) to capture the current moment on every mouse movement. Calculate the elapsed time with [`Duration.between`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#between(java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.time.temporal.Temporal)). When the [duration](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) exceeds an arbitrary limit, say 5 seconds, restart the Swing timer, and update the “when timer last restarted” `Instant` you store. `Instant.now` captures the current moment in a resolution of [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) in Java 8 and a resolution of [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) in Java 9 and later. (An `Instant` actually holds [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), but conventional computer clocks cannot run that fine.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution so far:
You could create an own `Thread` which sleeps for 2 seconds. If this time is over you can do whatever you want. If the mouse is getting moved, you could `interrupt` the `Thread` and repeate:

```
public class MyMouseMotionListener implements MouseMotionListener {

    private final Thread timerThread;

    public MyMouseMotionListener() {
        this.timerThread = new Thread(new SleeperThread());
        this.timerThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        this.timerThread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

And the Thread:

```
public class SleeperThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try{
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                System.out.println("Do Whatever you want.");
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Do nothing yet.");
            }
        }
    }

}
```